# Optaplanner Score calculation types questions

Tags: optaplanner

Solve the doubts on the use of OptaPlanner.
OptaPlanner uses the following score calculation types: **Drools score calculation or Constraint streams score calculation. Both methods support incremental calculation of scores**.
One doubt about incremental calculation of scores:

**Demo:**

```
import org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.CloudBalance;
import org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.CloudComputer;
import org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.domain.CloudProcess;

global HardSoftScoreHolder scoreHolder;

// ############################################################################
// Hard constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "requiredCpuPowerTotal"
    when
        $computer : CloudComputer($cpuPower : cpuPower)
        accumulate(
            CloudProcess(
                computer == $computer,
                $requiredCpuPower : requiredCpuPower);
            $requiredCpuPowerTotal : sum($requiredCpuPower);
            $requiredCpuPowerTotal > $cpuPower
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $cpuPower - $requiredCpuPowerTotal);
end
```

1. Assuming that the requiredCpuPowerTotal condition is established, the then logic is executed, and the hard score is added, assuming -100.
2. At this time, the CloudProcess solution has been changed. CloudComputer has reduced some of the CloudProcess reception so that it will not exceed the cpu limit of this computer CloudComputer. This condition does not hold.

**My questions are**:

1. If the condition is met for the first time, computer A allocates 2 threads to a computer with a total of 4 core CPUs, but the first time computer A has 2 cores, so this time the solution is a negative score of hard -100  .
2. The second program A computer allocates 1 thread, if the current conditions are not met, the negative score will not be increased.  The result is hard 0. Questions: 1. But how did the previous negative score be deleted?
3. Or does it mean that the score will be recalculated every new solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. The previous negative score will be deleted because `addHardConstraintMatch()` is doing some black magic: it registers a rule unmatch listener to undo that negative addition when the score no longer matches.
3. scoreDRL is incremental, so only the delta of the score change will be recalculated.

PS: Take a look at ConstraintStreams too, they are also incremental :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I also saw this part of the logic in the source code. Thank you